# How can I find my working directory?

Tags: html, apache, tomcat, firebug, tomcat7

You'll have to bear with my slightly on this, but please ask if I have left out any pertinent information. I have just taken over a project to create a dashboard for my team. This dashboard has been made using a niche third-party tool that nobody here will have used before. The third party tool auto-generates some code to display "markers" on a webpage. "Markers" being some proprietary code to query a database/apply custom styling etc.

I am trying to display a webpage within the page that has been generated, and I’d like to point this to a local webpage (ie on my C drive). If I pass it an absolute path, then this results in a warning in IE9 as I am mixing data sources - a https website pointing to a http web page. It will display after ignoring the warning, but my userbase is not comfortable enough with computers to ask them to do this.

I believe if I pass it a relative path then it should work, but I can’t find out what directory to base this path off and it doesn’t appear to be anywhere obvious. So, in my current page I have an image with the web address of : `https://website:8443/websitereport/images/buttons/locked.gif`. What I need to know is where the “websitereport/images” folder is stored so that I can put my webpage in there to give the webpage a relative path. The HTML for this image is :

```
<img id="dvp_locationbar_lock" class="dvp_imagebutton" style="" dvp_title="ui.tip.lock-page" dvp_image="locationBarPageUnlockedImage" src="/websitereport/images/buttons/unlocked.gif" title="Lock this page">
```

What are my options for discovering where this folder is stored locally? I am running Apache Tomcat 7.0. It is not displaying if I use the path based off

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\work\Catalina\websitereport
```

of

```
\websitereport\page.html
```

And I cannot find it anywhere obvious in the Apache folder. I have tried :

- Searching - no results.
- Using PHP to print the current working    directory - cannot find out
  where to edit the webpage.
- Looking at images/information on the existing webpage. They all point
  to folders I cannot find.
- Inspecting with firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't rely on the files being on disk at all - they might be just contained in a *.war file, containing the whole application. Or they might be generated on-the-fly, despite the name sounding like an actual file.

Also, you should not arbitrarily write within a directory even if you find it (my closest guess would be tomcat's `webapps/websitereport/` directory if it exists) because nobody will know that something changed during the time since last deployment. So, on the next update of the application, you'll end up overwriting all of your changes again. You typically change the underlying application and redeploy.

You might also find a few references in tomcat's `conf/localhost/` directory or even in `conf/server.xml`, but it all depends on how your server was administered

Comment: Right you are! Thanks very much for the help. If anyone else is stuck in this problem, the webpage was contained in a .war file. I was able to edit this by unzipping the .war file, making changes to it as I desired, and then jarring it using the .jar command command in the Java SDK - generating a .zip and changing the extension didn't work as a .manifest was not generated. Once I ran jar.exe on the file and changed the extension to .war, everything worked perfectly.